# sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen and sun.security.pkcs.PKCS10 - missing in JDK8. Implementation suggestions

Tags: java, security, x509certificate, pkcs#10

In JDK8 the class `sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen` does not exists anymore. Also `sun.security.pkcs.PKCS10` is missing. In JDK7 they existed. What could be an alternatives to these classes methods?

Comment: Why do you need to use implementation-specific classes instead of JCA API?

Comment: I was using those methods in my application - it is like `keytool.jar`, but has convenient user interface. Will back to it later, now busy with other projects. Temporary using JDK7 for that application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are looking for: [sun.security.tools.keytool.CertAndKeyGen](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/security/tools/keytool/CertAndKeyGen.java/)

You'll find it inside the **rt.jar** under the JRE libraries.

Keep in mind this class is outside of [J2SE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Standard_Edition), it's likely only available with [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK), so for example the [GNU Compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/java/) won't have it.

Comment: my tests on travis, which i believe is ubuntu, is that CertAndKeyGen is not available on any flavor of java for ubuntu, versions 6-8 openjdk or oracle

Comment: Adding rt.jar in the classpath solved the IntelliJ compilation issue.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using maven, put this in pom.xml. ([from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353565/maven-cant-compile-using-rt-jar)):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2</version>
  <configuration>
     <fork>true</fork>
     <compilerArgument>-XDignore.symbol.file</compilerArgument>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. Though I don't understand why.

Comment: I'm trying to build Openfire using Intellij IDEA. I have latest Java SDK 1.8 installed on my Win 10 machine. Got the same error on import sun.security.x509.GeneralNameInterface;. There are multiple pom.xml files, one global for a project folder, one in xmppserver subfolder. I tried to add the settings you described - it didn't fix error.

Comment: Got it.
Somehow on my machine there was JDK 11 installed besides JDK 1.8. How it got there I don’t remember… maybe team which initially prepared my laptop did it… I don’t know.
Then, in File->Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Project Project SDK was set to 11, not to 1.8. I don’t remember setting it… maybe IntelliJ IDEA chose maximum available when I first opened Openfire project?

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to the BouncyCastle API instead.

Comment: This is unlimited crypto unlock, it does not contain any classes at all.

Comment: Always trying not use third party libraries if possible - but some are to good to refuse :).