# Maven can't compile using rt.jar

Tags: java, maven

My project uses `sun.security.tools.keytool` to generate certificate under JDK 1.8 and this package can be found in `rt.jar`. According to [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism, System Dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies), I can add `rt.jar` as a dependency to my project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>rt.jar</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I'm pretty sure Maven found this jar file. However when I import `sun.security.tools.keytool.Main`, it still generates an error. Moreover, the most strange thing is if I copy `rt.jar` into someplace and fill its path in `pom.xml`, it works! As soon as I switch back to use the original `rt.jar`, it fails!

Can anyone tell me how could this happen?

Comment: `rt.jar` contains the runtime classes - so it shouldn't be required to include this jar as an explicit dependency at all...

Comment: I know... But heritrix (web crawler) uses this. So this problem prevents me from compiling heritrix...

Comment: Can you supply a link to the Maven wiki page you are referring to.

Comment: [maven system dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies)

Answer (score 26):

I created a Maven project and added the `<dependency>` of your question to its POM.

First I got:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] .../SO-31353565/src/main/java/igb/so/SO31353565.java:[6,34]
    package sun.security.tools.keytool does not exist
[ERROR] .../SO-31353565/src/main/java/igb/so/SO31353565.java:[12,50]
    cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Main
  location: class igb.so.SO31353565
```

Then, according to [Cannot find symbol (CertAndKeyGen) with JDK8](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/201405.mbox/%3c15A48219F4A84F489888721FF582FC63126FD0E533@QHEXMBOX2.hosting.inetserver.de%3e), I added:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <fork>true</fork>
          <compilerArgument>-XDignore.symbol.file</compilerArgument>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

to the POM and the compilation succeeded.

Comment: How to specify same in gradle? Any idea?

Comment: Hat off you man, you saved me i was looking for this since 5 hours thanks :)

Comment: I'm trying to build Openfire using Intellij IDEA. I have latest Java SDK 1.8 installed on my Win 10 machine. Got the same error on import sun.security.x509.GeneralNameInterface;. There are multiple pom.xml files, one global for a project folder, one in xmppserver subfolder. I tried to add the settings you described - it didn't fix error.

Comment: @vkelman Due to the multiple POMs: Did you try `mvn help:effective-pom` on the project in question to see whether the setting is really applied to it.

Comment: Thanks ;) Exact solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Gradle instead of Maven you can add this to your build:

```
compileJava {
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac'
    options.compilerArgs << "-XDignore.symbol.file"
}
```

It worked for me! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

1. Add to JAVA_HOME/lib/rt.jar
2. Go to Eclipse Menu Windows -> Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs
3. Select jdk version. In me case jdk-11.0.4
4. Select Add External JARs.. and add JAVA_HOME/lib/rt.jar

Comment: 1. With powerful build tools available nowadays copying dependencies around manually isn't state of the art.
2. Isn't it enough to refer to `.../jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar` in Eclipse?