# Migrating java from 8 to 11, sun.security.tools.keytool.CertAndKeyGen missing

Tags: migration, java-11, keytool

Migrating java from 8 to 11,

```
sun.security.tools.keytool.CertAndKeyGen 
sun.security.x509.X500Name
```

missing.

Which artifact(jar) should be added as dependency?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen and sun.security.pkcs.PKCS10 - missing in JDK8. Implementation suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29060064/sun-security-x509-certandkeygen-and-sun-security-pkcs-pkcs10-missing-in-jdk8)

Comment: In java 8, they are in lib/rt.jar. but not sure which one for java 11.  sun.security.* is not public API. I am wondering if there is a public API. thanks.